# How to clear text field using alike switch case in python

Tags: python, dictionary, selenium-webdriver, switch-statement

```
# this function clears text from fields.
    def clear_text(self, field):
        switcher = {
            'company': self.company_name_textbox_id,
            'email': self.email_textbox_id,
            'website': self.website_textbox_id,
            'phone': self.phone_textbox_id,
        }
        switcher.get(self.driver.find_element_by_id(field).clear(), "Invalid field provided")
```

```
    def test03_existing_company_validation(self):
        company = CompanyPage(self.driver)
        company.clear_text('company')
```

clear_text is not working. Am I doing it right? How to fix it?

Comment: Seems like you should probably be passing `field` to your switcher dictionary and then passing the value from that to `find_element_by_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your logic is going in the wrong order. You should probably be passing `field` to your switcher dictionary and then passing the value from that to `find_element_by_id`.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id(switcher[field]).clear()
```